# The browser can't recache updated website

Tags: javascript, php, service-worker, browser-cache, cache-control

I've completely rewritten a website, all it's resources have been moved to other folders (changed file structure) but if I access the site from a device that has cached it, it loads the old html file and looks for the old resource paths. I've tried to solve it with meta tags, I have changed the default index.php start file to home.php in .htaccess, I tried to solve it via js, but nothing works.
After days of searching, I think that I have found the problem. The webpage was transformed to a PWA and I registered a service worker for it to cache the index.php page. I think that this service worker's cache may be my problem. How can I update it in order to recache the website? The problem is, that I can update the index.php file however I want, the browser still loads the old file.

I am sure that it can be solved somehow, but I don't have any experiences with this. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
var cacheName = 'prisma-pwa';
var filesToCache = [
    '/',
];

/* Start the service worker and cache all of the app's content */
self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    })
  );
});
/* Serve cached content when offline */
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
  e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request).then(function(response) {
      return response || fetch(e.request);
    })
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In some few cases it's not enough to reset with F5 or even CTRL-F5. Here helps to really delete the cache in your browser.

If you use Chrome than you can disable in preferences the cache while using DevTools. This helps me sometimes. The little loss of perfomance doesn't bother me for testing.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, a hard refresh solves my problem, but I can't tell every user to do a hard refresh

Comment: I am hoping for an automated solution that solves it for every user

Comment: I understand your problem this is a problem with caching and it's not only the browser cache sometimes there is a proxy between who makes the same problems.

Comment: One possible solution could be to add to the URL at the end a parameter so the caching can't act. This could be something like `/myApp.html?versionId=1679`. Try it out, I haven't tested it.